# App with Swift code crashing on launch after deployment

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

Our app contains Swift code. We changed the target's Embedded Content Contains Swift Code value to *Yes* and revoked then recreated our certificates. After signing the IPA with our developer's certificate, we sent it to our client. They resigned with their distribution certificate and deployed the app in their own App Store. After successful installation, the app crashes on launch with the following log.

> .... Frameworks/libswiftCore.dylib not valid: 0xe8008015: A valid
>   provisioning profile for this executable was not found...

I̶ ̶d̶o̶ ̶n̶o̶t̶ ̶t̶h̶i̶n̶k̶ this is the same issue as [Technical Q&A QA1886](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/qa/qa1886/_index.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So out of desperation, we revoked and recreated our client's distribution cert. And it worked! This is the same issue as the Technical QA even though the error messages are different.